# Way to quickly fetch distinct values from indexed collection field in Orient?

Tags: indexing, orientdb

Is there an efficient way to get distinct values from a multi-value field (set or list) that is indexed?

So far I found that:

```
select distinct(key) from index:V.indexedField
```

works efficiently, but only for simple (single value) fields and only for index of type NOTUNIQUE (for NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX it throws UOE)

It does also execute for multi-value fields but results do not resemble anything meaningful.

I tried

```
select distinct(expand(field)) from V
```

but apparently it does not take advantage of index, iterates all vertices and blows up memory for larger database.

Perhaps there's a way to do it from Java API ?

Comment: Hi rohrl, another way to use indexes and work with unique data is to create a `UNIQUE` type index (`SB-TREE` or `HASH`, single or composite) on one or multiple fields.

Comment: Hi rohrl, just for completness, which version of OrientDB are you using ?

Comment: Hi Luca, I'm using Orient 2.1.9

Answer (score 0):

I tried your case with this dataset:

[image]

and these are my indexes:

[image]

I used OrientDB 2.1.13 and all indexes (4 tried) work correctly. I attach the executed queries.

1. `explain select from v where name = 'a'` (`UNIQUE SB-TREE`)

[image]

2. `explain select from v where name2 = 'e'` (`NOTUNIQUE SB-TREE`)

[image]

3. `explain select from v where name3 = 'l'` (`UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX`)

[image]

4. `explain select from v where name4 = 'o'` (`NOTUNIQUE_HASH_INDEX`)

[image]

Probably your problem is the missed usage of the `WHERE` clause (which checks and matches indexes) because without this it happens a simple scan of the class.

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi Luca, thanks for the reply.
The queries you proposed will not help me, as I'm trying to collect all distinct values that are present under a given field across all records in database. 
Luckily, after further research I found that sometimes my query does work:
`select distinct(key) from index:V.indexedField`
will work on NOTUNIQUE index (so in other words it won't work for hash index)
And you're right with `where` clause - if I add it to my query it also works for hash-based index. But I can't use `where` because I want to scan all records...

Comment: ... so my next question is, how can I make it work for hash-based indexes?

Comment: I also noticed in the 2nd screenshot, that all your indexes have Engine = Sb-tree. I thought hash-based indexes do not use SB-TREE, am I wrong here?